connecting to ibm MQ with TLS
I get an error when trying to connect to ibm mq:
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|10|main|2024-07-11 15:28:58.816 MSK|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
)

my docker compose, volume qmdata contains the created certificates:
services:
  ibmmq:
    image: 'docker.io/ibmcom/mq'
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
      - MQ_APP_PASSWORD=qwe
      - MQ_TLS_KEYSTORE=/mnt/mqm/MQServer/certs/key.p12
      - MQ_TLS_PASSPHRASE=qwe
    ports:
      - '1414:1414'
      - '9443:9443'
    volumes:
      - ibmmq:/data/ibmmq
      - ./config.mqsc:/etc/mqm/config.mqsc
      - qmdata:/mnt/mqm
    container_name: ibmmq

volumes:
  ibmmq:
    driver: local
  qmdata:

/mnt/mqm/MQServer/certs/key.p12 contains certificates created as follows:
cd /mnt/mqm
mkdir -p MQServer/certs
cd MQServer/certs
runmqakm -keydb -create -db key.p12 -pw qwe -type pkcs12 -expire 1000 -stash
runmqakm -cert -create -db key.p12 -label ibmwebspheremqqm1 -dn "cn=qm,o=ibm,c=uk" -size 2048 -default_cert yes -stashed
runmqakm -cert -extract -db key.p12 -stashed -label ibmwebspheremqqm1 -target QM1.cert

cd ../..
mkdir -p MQClient/certs
cd MQClient/certs
runmqakm -keydb -create -db client_key.p12 -pw qwe -type pkcs12 -expire 1000
runmqakm -cert -add -label QM1.cert -db client_key.p12 -type pkcs12 -pw qwe -trust enable -file ../../MQServer/certs/QM1.cert

config.mqsc contains these commands:
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12)
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)

my application jms config:
        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
        factory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, Integer.valueOf(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT));
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
        factory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "*TLS12");


What error shows up in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG?

Is the app using the DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel for messaging?

@JoshMC Error in AMQERR01.LOG:
AMQ9645E: Certificate label 'ibmwebspheremqqm1' not found for channel '????'.

What does "DIS QMGR SSLKEYR" show, does it match the path to the key db?

The error states: SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake there's a number of reasons that this could happen and the queue manager logs will be able to tell you excatly why it rejected the communication... but i suspect your issue here is that you're enforcing Mutual TLS on the channel via the channel attribute SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED). But i see no mention of a client certificate (only server side).
If this is the case you have two choices:

Change the SSLCAUTH setting on the DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel to be OPTIONAL not required.
Create a certificate for the Java application to use, exchanging that certificate so the queue manager will trust it.

